# tcp packet injection -?

Tags: tcp, packet-injection

i have TCP client on host 192.168.1.13 reading data from static ip 176.132.74.74 ...
i need to inject crafted packets into this connection to test if my firewall can filter out spoofed traffic. 
I've tried "nemesis" 1.4beta3 from the host 192.168.1.15:
nemesis tcp -v -D 192.168.1.13 -S 176.132.74.74 -fS -fA 
but got an error:
"Unable to allocate socket descriptor"
TCP urgent pointer: 0
I am making some error in using of nemesis, or can i only use it from the same host ( 192.168.1.13)?
Are there other similar tools i could use to this purpose?
i'd appreciate some advise: there's not much of it i could find on using of nemesis

Comment: use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

Comment: Any idea if i can craft packet payload with scapy? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you can see http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/BuildAndDissect

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/). Is a high level library for C++ to generate and sniff network packets. And also contains a very naive implementation of the TCP/IP stack (fragmentation is no handled yet) at USER level that enables working with crafted TCP streams. For example you can control the ACK and SEQ numbers of a connection, or use the SEQ/ACK numbers and IPs of an already established connection. So, is possible to inject traffic to a connection and also hijack it.

At USER level I mean that the library works with TCP streams on "kernel's back". So, to properly use the TCP stream class, you need to work a little with IPTABLES.

Although there isn't a documentation for the TCPConnection class (yet), you can take a look at some examples on the "examples" git repository.

Cheers.